# Vllookup, match, index

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am trying to compare data from one sheet to another. Address and its ID.
Both sheets have Address and ID. ID can be repetitive.

```
Sheet 1                       Sheet 2
Address           ID           Address       ID
23                 1              22          1 
45                 1              45          1 
23                 2              23          2
45                 2              45          3
```

I want to check whether the data address & ID on sheet 1 appear on Sheet 2 thus making a new row with return Yes or No on sheet 1 for every column.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very quickly with an array formula.

**Picture of ranges and result** shows the data on the same sheet so that it is easier to see what is going on.  Pretend `Sheet1` is on the left and `Sheet2` is on the right.

[image: ranges]

**Formula** in cell `D3` is an array formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) and then copied down to fill.

```
=(B3=$F$3:$F$6)*(C3=$G$3:$G$6)
```

This formula will simple return a `0  or 1` for `no match/match`.  You can wrap it in an `IF` if you want text instead.  It is simply checking that the relevant values match for both columns in both "sheets".